# Issue with RayCast3d with detecting player in godot 4.2.1

Tags: game-development, godot

I am working on an enemy that uses a simple raycast to detect if a player is in front of them, then to begin chasing the player. However I get this error when run: "Attempt to call function 'is_in_group' in base 'null instance' on a null instance."

Here's the code:

```
    extends CharacterBody3D
    
    var player = null
    
    var health = 100
    
    const SPEED = 4.0
    const ATTACK_RANGE = 2.0

    @export var player_path : NodePath
    @onready var nav_agent = $NavigationAgent3D
    @onready var view_ray = $MeshInstance3D/RayCast3D

    var player_found = false

    # Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
    func _ready():
    player = get_node(player_path)
    
    
    # Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
    func _process(delta):
    velocity = Vector3.ZERO
    
    if(player_found == true):
        nav_agent.set_target_position(player.global_transform.origin)
        var next_nav_point = nav_agent.get_next_path_position()
        velocity = (next_nav_point - global_transform.origin).normalized() * SPEED
    
        look_at(Vector3(player.global_position.x, global_position.y, player.global_position.z), Vector3.UP)
    
    if(player_found == false):
        pass
    
    if view_ray.get_collider().is_in_group("Player") and view_ray.get_collider() != null:
            player_found = true
    
    if view_ray.get_collider() == null:
        player_found = false
    
    move_and_slide()


    func _target_in_range():
    return global_position.distance_to(player.global_position) < ATTACK_RANGE


    func _hit_finished():
    if global_position.distance_to(player.global_position) < ATTACK_RANGE + 1.0:
        var dir = global_position.direction_to(player.global_position)
        player.hit(dir)

    func hit():
    health -= 33
    if (health == 0 or health < 0):
        queue_free()
```

Here's the node structure:

```
VC_scout
  MeshInstance3D
    RayCast3D
  CollisionShape3D
  NavigationAgent3D
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that you are calling `is_in_group` on `null`. Since you call `is_in_group` in this part of the code:

```
    if view_ray.get_collider().is_in_group("Player") and view_ray.get_collider() != null:
            player_found = true
```

We have to conclude that `view_ray.get_collider()` is `null`. Which would mean that the ray didn't collide.

And yes, you are checking if `view_ray.get_collider() != null`, but you are checking that *AFTER* you try to call `is_in_group`.

Thus, you should be able to solve this swapping the checks:

```
    if view_ray.get_collider() != null and view_ray.get_collider().is_in_group("Player"):
            player_found = true
```

Since we have an `and`, and `and` is only `true` when the conditions are `true`... If one of the conditions is `false`, we know the result will be `false` without checking the other. So when `view_ray.get_collider() != null` is `false` (i.e. when `view_ray.get_collider()` is `null`) Godot can skip checking  `view_ray.get_collider().is_in_group("Player")`.

To be completely clear, Godot will evaluate the bool conditions from left to right, and will short-circuit (i.e. exit early) if possible. This is a common feature in many programming languages, see [Short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).